# Have custom styled radio button selected by default

Tags: css

I have a custom styled radio button, and with that it doesn't respond to `selected="selected"` within its tag. Is there any other solution to make it selected?

This is the custom code, so as you can see the original is just hidden. If I try to click submit on the form with the default `selected="selected"` on, it says I need to fill out all fields (on only the radio - but the notice appears in the top left of my browser).

```
label {  
    display: inline-block;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    position: relative;  
    padding-left: 25px;  
    margin-right: 15px;  
    font-size: 13px;  
}  

input[type=radio] {  
    display: none;  
}  

label:before {  
    content: "";  
    display: inline-block;  

    width: 12px;  
    height: 12px;  

    margin-right: 10px;  
    position: absolute;  
    left: 0; 
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #c8ccce;  

}  

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {  
    content: '\2713';  
    color: green;  
    font-size: 12px;  
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 12px;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIKE THIS ?

`<input type="radio" name="car" value="850" id="small" checked>`
The 'checked' attribute.

http://codepen.io/jacobgDK/pen/ZYxmdp
Used it here myself, hope it is the right answer.

Comment: I think this is correct and it is due to there being a difference between selected and checked. And when it comes to Radio buttons you should use checked

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to use `checked`. I've been using so many drop-down selects recently that `selected` is just engraved in my mind. Thanks.